# JAVA Property editor window like netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, editor, properties

Im trying to create a netbeans like property window in a jframe/jpanel.

Can anyone give me a link to a tutorial/example of using a property window (it must by a dynamic window, not hard coded).

P.S. The tutorial of netbeans.org is not what im looking for, it's about CHANGING the property window inside netbeans, not putting it into my form/panel.

Thanks,

Greets.